# Pandas: Drop rows at beginning of groups if a column equals certain string value ('Sell' or 'Buy')

Tags: python, pandas, finance, fifo

To clarify, the 'group' in the title is not a result of pd.groupby. Instead, I meant it as rows that share the same values of certain columns. In my case it would be **account** and **symbol**.

I am trying to calculate profits&loss by account and position from trade data on a First-in, first-out (FIFO). As a result, when cumulative share quantities drops below zero, namely, when the most recent sell shares is bigger than all the buy shares prior combined, I need to reset it to 0. Same deal when the trade data begins with sell records.

I am trying to design a cumulative sum which will reset to 0 to help with the process. What I have is:

```
    def cumsum_with_reset(group):
        cumulative_sum = 0
        group['reset_cumsum'] = 0
        for index, row in group.iterrows():
            cumulative_sum += row['Modified_Quantity']
            if cumulative_sum < 0:
                cumulative_sum = 0
            group.loc[index, 'reset_cumsum'] = cumulative_sum
        return group
```

This function can return 0 if a group, namely the rows with the same account and symbol, begins with sell records. However, the problem is iterrows is so inefficient that it takes forever for large amount of data so I want to create a new function but I am stuck at the very first step: how to remove the **sell** rows in each group before the **buy** rows?

Using some sample data:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = [['2022-01-01', 'foo', 'AMZN', 'buy', 10, 22],
 ['2022-01-02', 'foo', 'AMZN', 'sell', 15, 24],
 ['2022-01-03', 'cat', 'FB', 'sell', 5, 12],
 ['2022-01-04', 'cat', 'FB', 'buy', 17, 15],
 ['2022-01-05', 'cat', 'FB', 'sell', 15, 13],
 ['2022-01-06', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'buy', 10, 10],
 ['2022-01-07', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'buy', 5, 12],
 ['2022-01-08', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'sell', 8, 12],
 ['2022-01-09', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'sell', 12, 14],
 ['2022-01-10', 'dog', 'GOOG', 'sell', 20, 13],
 ['2022-01-11', 'dog', 'GOOG', 'buy', 15, 13],
 ['2022-01-12', 'dog', 'GOOG', 'buy', 5, 13],
 ['2022-01-13', 'dog', 'GOOG', 'sell', 7, 14]], columns = ['Date', 'account', 'symbol', 'Action', 'Quantity', 'Price'])
```

which looks like this:

[image: sample]

There are 4 groups in this dataset:

[image: grouped]

2nd and 4th group start with sell records, row 2 and row 9. How can I use Pandas to get rid of such records until each group starts with buy records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty trivial if there no more than one sell in the beginning of a group:

```
# assuming df is sorted by symbol + date
df.loc[(df['symbol'] == df['symbol'].shift()) | (df['Action'] != 'sell')]
```

If multiple consequtive sells are to be removed, we'll need to track state of the previous row removal:

```
last = False
df.loc[[not (last := (action == 'sell' and (last or current != prev)))  
        for action, current, prev  
        in zip(df['Action'], df['symbol'], df['symbol'].shift())]]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot for your answer and introducing walrus operator to me. I had to really study that and learn your logic. This works like a charm. Thanks again. If you don't mind, I have another question in the process of developing the FIFO function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76293190/5336013 If you care to take a look Marat.