# Python Pandas: how to subtract value of column A in the last row of each group from column B of certain rows in the group in reverse order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

To clarify, the 'group' in the title is not a result of pd.groupby. Instead, I meant it as rows that share the same values of certain columns. In my case it would be account and security_id.

I am trying to calculate profits&loss by account and position from trade data on a First-in, first-out (FIFO). Therefore, for each account and security_id when cumulative buy share quantities exceed total sell quantities, I need to trim the excess of the bought shares from the bottom up: subtracting from the last buy order, and then the 2nd last buy... until all the excess shares are subtracted from buy orders and total buy shares match total sell shares.

Some sample data (thanks to @Marat 's help, I could remove the initial sell orders before first buy order in each group):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['2022-01-01', 'foo', 'AMZN', 'buy', 18, 22],
 ['2022-01-02', 'foo', 'AMZN', 'sell', 15, 24],
 ['2022-01-03', 'cat', 'FB', 'buy', 17, 12],
 ['2022-01-04', 'cat', 'FB', 'buy', 5, 15],
 ['2022-01-05', 'cat', 'FB', 'sell', 15, 13],
 ['2022-01-06', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'buy', 19, 10],
 ['2022-01-07', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'buy', 3, 12],
 ['2022-01-08', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'sell', 12, 12],
 ['2022-01-09', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'sell', 5, 14]], columns = ['Date', 'account', 'security_id', 'Action', 'Quantity', 'Price'])
```

There are 3 groups in the sample dataframe above, and the buy shares exceed the sell shares in each group. I was able to calculate the excess using the simple code below.

```
df.loc[df['Action'] == 'buy', 'Modified_Quantity'] = df['Quantity']
df.loc[df['Action'] == 'sell', 'Modified_Quantity'] = -df['Quantity']
df['reset_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['account', 'security_id'])['Modified_Quantity'].cumsum()
```

Now the result looks like this, with the excess of each group highlighted:
[image: excess]

I want to deduct the highlighted value from buy records in each group from the bottom up. The caveat is that sometimes the excess is bigger than an entire buy record. In that case I would make that buy record have quantity 0 and then subtract the remaining from the prior buy record.

My desired result would look like 'Updated_Quantity' below:

[image: Desired result]

I was able to eventually get the result by very tedious steps: creating a new buy dataframe, reversing the order, and then merging to the original dataframe, using groupby and merging a few times in the process. I think there must be an easier and more Pythonic way to achieve this. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: to clarify what I meant by 'excess' and how I reached the desired numbers in the last table. 'Excess' is the result of sum of buy shares subtracted by sum of sell shares in each group.

Using the example here:

1. First group: buy 18 and sell 15. Excess is 18-15 = 3 which is the part in the blue square. What I want to do is subtract 3 from the buy, 18 so it becomes 15.
2. Second group: buy 17+5 =22 and sell 15. Excess is 22-15 = 7 which is the part in the red square. I want to subtract 7 from the buy records. However the 2nd buy record only has 5 in total, so it becomes 0. I still have 7-5 = 2 to subtract from other buys. So the first buy becomes 17-2 = 15
3. Third group: buy 19+3 =22 and sell 12+5 = 17. Excess is 22-17 = 5 which is the part in the green square. I want to subtract 5 from the buy records. However the 2nd buy record only has 3 in total, so it becomes 0. I still have 5-3 = 2 to subtract from other buys. So the first buy becomes 19-2 = 17

Comment: The logic is not fully clear, can you break down the computations? For instance, I don't understand how you get `17`. Also, how do you define "*excess*"? Is this the last value per group?

Comment: @mozway You are absolutely right. I tried to read this as an outsider myself and I got confused. I added some clarification and hopefully it makes more sense to audience now. I suck at explaining pandas problems in text. Basically excess is (sum of buy shares - sum of sell shares) and then I want to gradually subtract excess from buy records from the bottom up. Thanks mozway

Comment: @mozway Was the edit able to clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to compute your desired outcome using a vectorized approach:

- **Step 1:** Some helper columns are created which allow us to filter the `DataFrame` and manipulate certain values based on conditions. These 'internal' columns will be removed again at the end.
- **Step 2:** Another helper column (`_buy_correction` ) will be created to perform the actual computation, where we combine in that column the `excess of each group` as a negative number (the `excess` only appears in the last `sell` row per `security_id`) with the `Quantity` of the `buy` rows. `np.NaNs` (which appear in `sell` rows which do not contain the `excess`) are filled with 0.
- **Step 3:** `Updated_Quantity` is derived by inverting the `DataFrame`, grouping by `security_id`, computing the `cumulative sum` per group of `_buy_correction`, and undoing the inversion of the row order. Subsequently, the values of all `sell` rows are replaced by their values in `Quantity`. Last, the value `0` is assigned to all `buy` rows with negative values in `Updated_Quantity`.
- **Step 4:** All internal columns are removed

The logic is implemented below:

```
# Code of OP
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        ['2022-01-01', 'foo', 'AMZN', 'buy', 18, 22],
        ['2022-01-02', 'foo', 'AMZN', 'sell', 15, 24],
        ['2022-01-03', 'cat', 'FB', 'buy', 17, 12],
        ['2022-01-04', 'cat', 'FB', 'buy', 5, 15],
        ['2022-01-05', 'cat', 'FB', 'sell', 15, 13],
        ['2022-01-06', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'buy', 19, 10],
        ['2022-01-07', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'buy', 3, 12],
        ['2022-01-08', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'sell', 12, 12],
        ['2022-01-09', 'bar', 'AAPL', 'sell', 5, 14]],
    columns = ['Date', 'account', 'security_id', 'Action', 'Quantity', 'Price']
 )
df.loc[df['Action'] == 'buy', 'Modified_Quantity'] = df['Quantity']
df.loc[df['Action'] == 'sell', 'Modified_Quantity'] = -df['Quantity']
df['reset_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['account', 'security_id'])['Modified_Quantity'].cumsum()

# STEP 1: Compute helper columns for filtering logic
df['_rank'] = df['security_id'].groupby(df['security_id']).transform('rank', method='first')
df['_last_row'] = df['_rank'] != df['_rank'].shift(-1) - 1
df['_sell_row'] = df['Action'] == 'sell'
df['_buy_row'] = df['Action'] == 'buy'

# STEP 2: Construct helper column for computation of 'Updated_Quantity'
df['_buy_correction'] = np.NaN
df.loc[df['_last_row'], '_buy_correction'] = df['_buy_correction'].fillna(df['reset_cumsum']) * -1
df.loc[df['_buy_row'], '_buy_correction'] = df['_buy_correction'].fillna(df['Modified_Quantity'])
df['_buy_correction'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Step 3: Update Quantity
df['Updated_Quantity'] = df.loc[::-1, ['security_id', '_buy_correction']].groupby('security_id').cumsum()[::-1]
df.loc[df['_sell_row'], 'Updated_Quantity'] = df['Quantity']
df.loc[df['Updated_Quantity']<0, 'Updated_Quantity'] = 0

# Step 4: Cleanup
drop_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("_")]
df.drop(columns=drop_cols, inplace=True)

# Print Result
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Result:

```
| Date       | account   | security_id   | Action   |   Quantity |   Price |   Modified_Quantity |   reset_cumsum |   Updated_Quantity |
|:-----------|:----------|:--------------|:---------|-----------:|--------:|--------------------:|---------------:|-------------------:|
| 2022-01-01 | foo       | AMZN          | buy      |         18 |      22 |                  18 |             18 |                 15 |
| 2022-01-02 | foo       | AMZN          | sell     |         15 |      24 |                 -15 |              3 |                 15 |
| 2022-01-03 | cat       | FB            | buy      |         17 |      12 |                  17 |             17 |                 15 |
| 2022-01-04 | cat       | FB            | buy      |          5 |      15 |                   5 |             22 |                  0 |
| 2022-01-05 | cat       | FB            | sell     |         15 |      13 |                 -15 |              7 |                 15 |
| 2022-01-06 | bar       | AAPL          | buy      |         19 |      10 |                  19 |             19 |                 17 |
| 2022-01-07 | bar       | AAPL          | buy      |          3 |      12 |                   3 |             22 |                  0 |
| 2022-01-08 | bar       | AAPL          | sell     |         12 |      12 |                 -12 |             10 |                 12 |
| 2022-01-09 | bar       | AAPL          | sell     |          5 |      14 |                  -5 |              5 |                  5 |
```